# how to stable hover effect even after mouse out

Tags: html, css, jscript

how to set my hover effect stable even after mouse out ???
    code is working fine but after mouse out div element comes to its
    original state ??

html

```
<div id="sme"></div>
```

css

```
#sme{
    width: 400px;
    height: 400px;
    border: 20px solid #06c999;
/* Rotate */
}
#sme:hover{
transition: all 1.9s ease;
 -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(180deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(180deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(180deg);
    transform: rotate(180deg);

}
```

Comment: I think you need to use jQuery or Javascript

Comment: If your intention is to keep it that way after the initial hover event, you may want to consider using javascript to add a class with those state-change values, rather than binding them to a css `:hover` state. If you only need a temporary delay, before returning the element back to it's initial state, you could remove the class again after a short `setTimeout` function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something to consider is to use the animation play state. Side effect however is when you remove the mouse while the animation hasn't finished, the animation will pause.

```css
#sme {
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  border: 20px solid #06c999;
  animation: rotatebox 2s ease forwards;
  animation-play-state: paused;
}

#sme:hover {
  animation-play-state: running;
}

@keyframes rotatebox {
  100% {
    transform: rotate(180deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="sme">A</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Transition must be put in the normal state.

```css
#sme {
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  border: 20px solid #06c999;
  transition: all 1.9s ease;
}

#sme:hover {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(180deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(180deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(180deg);
  transform: rotate(180deg);
}
```

```html
<div id="sme"></div>
```

Edit : Indeed, if you want it to keep the state, i suggest to change #sme:hover by .hovered and add this class in js to your #sme when you hover it.

Answer (score 0):

You must have to use animations and add a class when you `hover` the element like

```js
function hasClass(element, cls) {
  return (' ' + element.className + ' ').indexOf(' ' + cls + ' ') > -1;
}

document.getElementById('sme').addEventListener('mouseover', function() {
  if (!hasClass(this, 'animated')) {
    this.className = 'animated';
  }
});
```

```css
#sme {
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  border: 20px solid #06c999;
  transition-property: transform;
  transition-duration: 1.9s;
}

#sme:hover,
.animated {
  animation-name: rotate;
  animation-duration: 2s;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-timing-function: linear;
}

@keyframes rotate {
  from {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  to {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="sme"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for this

```js
$(function(){
    $('#sme').on('mouseenter', function(){
 $(this).addClass('hoverd');
    });
});
```

```css
#sme {
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  border: 20px solid #06c999;
  transition: all 1.9s ease;
}

.hoverd {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(180deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(180deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(180deg);
  transform: rotate(180deg);
}
```

```html
<div id="sme"></div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
```